# Importing firebase auth users into a project from storage

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-cli

I have a `backups` folder in my firestore cloud console that contains all authenticated users. This JSON file, has been created by the auth users from a different project, but then imported into this one.

I am now trying to use `firebase auth:import` to add them to the authenticated tab on firestore but I am getting the following error:

> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'gs://bunk-demo-app-backups/backups/20-08-31T22:00:53Z/users/users.json'

I have tried running the following command:

```
firebase auth:import gs://bunk-demo-app-backups/backups/20-08-31T22:00:53Z/users/users.json --hash-algo=SCRYPT --hash-key=`key` --salt-separator=`salt` --rounds=8 --mem-cost=14 --debug
```

Following this flow: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/auth

But It is still not recognising this as the correct file path, even though in the following screenshot, you can see that it is the exact path.

[image]

I do have full permissions for this project, so I'm not quite sure why the path cant be found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that you can use the `firebase auth:import` CLI command with a file stored in Cloud Storage.

If I am not mistaking, the JSON (or CSV) file should be on the same machine that triggers the CLI command.

You could download the file from Cloud Storage and trigger the `firebase auth:import` CLI command with the corresponding "local" file path/name.